# change order of css files in header

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating a child theme for an existing theme. When setting up I noticed a few layout changes for the child theme cf the parent theme. Eventually I have worked out that this is due to the header pulling in the css files in a different order.

In the parent it goes:

1. pile of css files
2. theme styles.css

In the child them it goes:

1. theme styles.css
2. pile of css files
3. child styles.css

I want to get the order in the child them same, but just have the child one added on at the end,

In my child functions.php I have this.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

I have tried adding an large index to the end of the add_action call but that just messes things up even more.

So, how can I get the files in the right order please

Answer (score 0):

Your add_action function has a 'priority' argument you can use

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: yes, I have tried that as explained in my question. It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked the priority of the other actions (the parent theme)? It's all interconnected, so you should create an organic priority flow for it to work.

Comment: good thought. Went and found a function called themename_enqueue_styles which has a whole pile of code for importing various css files into it. Should I do something with that?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass an arg on add_action for priority like

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pile_name_scripts', 5 );
```

With 5 being loaded before the default priority of 10.

Comment: thanks - not sure what you mean 'pile_name_scripts'?

Comment: that's an example name function where you define what to attach to add_action hook (wp_enqueue_style or wp_enqueue_script)